# Certificate Error on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, ssl

Every time I open Stack Overflow this happens. But on my laptop it's working fine. This is just only on my PC.

[image: Expired certificate error]

Comment: Its the same problem, as the dupe target and vaguely randomly affecting folks and not just on SE

Comment: Found it ;D https://i.stack.imgur.com/orJ8h.png